# How to Sign Out / Log out of Twitter using Oauth on android?

Tags: android, integration, twitter-oauth

I am doing a Twitter integration.

I do not know how to log out of Twitter.

I am using the following code to try logout... but it's just removing the tokens:

```
        try
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
            edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
            edit.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not logging out of twitter. You are just removing the `OAUTH_TOKEN` keys from internal storage (`Shared Preferences`).

Comment: ya.. i knw that i m jst removing d token key from d internal storage...!! i had jst specified whtevr i tried..!! so may i knw how to logout from it? if u r knwing

Comment: @dangi - please read your previous comment _out loud_, does it make any sense whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void onTwitterLogout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        mTwitter.resetAccessToken();


    }   else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "You are already logout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

}
```

Comment: Twitter mTwitter;   This is object of twitter4j.Twitter class

Comment: Now Twitter change his api, Please see latest api implementation 
here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459344/display-twitter-feed-in-android-app-using-twitter-api-1-1/17166223#17166223

Comment: Doesn't have resetAccessToken.