# Display twitter feed in Android App using twitter API 1.1

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

Basically i want to show this feed : https://en.twitter.com/epl_live in my app. Since twitter changed its api 1.1 every call has to be authorised and all examples i'm finding are once which the user has to lg in to twitter and authorise my app.

This is stupid and time consuming for just displaying a feed as i don't want no personally info other than the tweets.

Is there a simple way to do this? anyone got any working scripts which pull in a feed from twitter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?id=epl_live&count=200&page=3, you can also ask for the JSON with:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?id=epl_live&count=200&page=3

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: These are [version 1.0 calls](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

Comment: Indeed, you explained it far better than me in your response, basically you will have to keep using the 1.0 until de new release of the API is ready. Thanks Jan,

Comment: Ive tried this but i get this responce:

[{"error":"This method requires a GET.","request":"\/1\/statuses\/user_timeline.json?id=epl_live&count=10"}]

Comment: My fault i was using HttpPost :/ pulls json through now

Answer (score 3):

With version 1.1 of the Twitter API doing calls without the authorization of a user is not yet possible, but [will be soon](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Authentication_required_on_all_endpoints):

> At this time, all authentication requires user context, but in the coming weeks we'll be pushing out support for a form of authentication not requiring a user context.

They will probably release some way to have your application authenticated directly without any user login involved.

For the moment you have to rely on version 1.0 of the API, which [is still supported](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview#Deprecation_of_v1.0_of_the_API):

> We will be providing a 6 month window before turning off v1.0. Starting March 5th, 2013, the 1.0 endpoints will no longer be available.

Comment: So your advice is use 1.0 untill 1.1 supports non user context authentication?

Comment: Exactly. Probably also your only option :)

Answer (score 3):

Full source code for twitter intregartion with API 1.1,
Checkout this code

https://github.com/dwivedi/twitter_api_1.1_implementation.git

Comment: Please update to twitter4j version 3.0.5 to be able to solve the login to twitter error. And it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

How would you build this in an android app? My layout is to press a button and it brings up another layer of the app. On that layer, it should display the Twitter feed that I require.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Thank you Mark for the edit. Sometime when I type out questions my brain says one thing and my fingers do another.